# SSH connects, but scp is having an issue - AWS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, scp, pem

I am able to connect to ssh using the command

```
ssh -i pem_filename.pem xx.xx.x.xx -l ec2-user
```

However, if i try to copy the file from the server to local machine using

```
scp -i pem_filename.pem ec2-user@ec2-xx-xx-x-xx.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com:html.zip .
```

I get the following error

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname ec2-xx-xx-x-xx.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com: 
nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

I tried with

```
scp -i pem_filename.pem ec2-user@ec2-xx-xx-x-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:html.zip .
```

but the result is the same.

Can anyone please guide where the issue is and oblige

Comment: Did you try with the IP address instead of the DNS name?

Comment: I think i am using IP address itself in the place of xx.xx.x.xx

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible you didn't enable [DNS hostnames](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-dns.html#vpc-dns-hostnames) when you created your VPC. Try this:

```
scp -i pem_filename.pem ec2-user@<ip-address>:/full/path/html.zip .
```

Example:

```
scp -i pem_filename.pem ec2-user@56.23.12.121:/home/ec2-user/html.zip .
```